# extract the type of prop in an object definition

Tags: typescript

In an interface I have the following prop definition:

```
interface AutocompleteProps {
...
  slotProps?: {
    clearIndicator?: Partial<IconButtonProps>;
    paper?: PaperProps;
    popper?: Partial<PopperProps>;
    popupIndicator?: Partial<IconButtonProps>;
  };
}
```

In my interface I want to create a prop based on the type of `slotProps.clearIndicator`, so I did as following:

```
clearIndicatorSlotProps: AutocompleteProps<
    T,
    true,
    DisableClearable,
    FreeSolo
  >['slotProps']['clearIndicator'];
```

Buy this didn't work and gave me the following error:

[image]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: The code snippet for the `AutocompleteProps` isn't generic, but you are passing parameters to it in your usage. Please update the interace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `slotProps` can be undefined.

One solution is to set the option `strict` to `false` in your tsconfig.json, but maybe there is a reason why it is set to `true` in the first place ?

I see two better solutions that can helps you

First one is to use the generic type `NonNullable` every time you try to access a property of an optional object :

```
clearIndicatorSlotProps: NonNullable<AutocompleteProps['slotProps']>['clearIndicator']
```

The other one would simply be to define a SlotProps type or interface so that it can be used directly without relying on the AutocompleteProps interface, and rewriting `AutocompleteProps` like this :

```
interface AutocompleteProps {
  ...
  slotProps?: SlotProps;
}
```